# How to convert the labels from integers to vectors in python jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I m trying to apply the correct code but always generate me an error.Here is code

```
trainY =keras.utils.to_categorical(trainY, num_classes=2, dtype='float32')
testY = keras.utils.to_categorical(testY, num_classes=2, dtype='float32')
```

It will generate an error that is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-dea4d664a742> in <module>
      1 # convert the labels from integers to vectors
----> 2 trainY =keras.utils.to_categorical(trainY ,num_classes=2, dtype='float32')
      3 testY = keras.utils.to_categorical(testY, num_classes=2, dtype='float32')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py in to_categorical(y, num_classes, dtype)
     41     """
     42 
---> 43     y = np.array(y, dtype='int')
     44     input_shape = y.shape
     45     if input_shape and input_shape[-1] == 1 and len(input_shape) > 1:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Help me.thanks in advannce.

Comment: Guess the input `trainY` in Line-2 is of type `None` and doesn't contain any value. Could you print and check the contents of `trainY`? It should ideally be of type `<class 'list'>` of integers.

Comment: What do you get when you type `print(trainY)` and `print(type(trainY))`?

Comment: when i print(trainY) It will display the same error

Comment: go a cell up , create a new cell below and print(type(trainY)) . Must show NoneType. There is an issue with your trainY I suppose.

Comment: how this solve this kindly write the code for this that is correct

Comment: Please only post questions once.